# cannot perform npm install - getting error 401

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

I am trying to run npm install on my PC ( windows 11, node v20.10.0, npm 10.2.3)

Getting error :

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Incorrect or missing password.
npm ERR! If you were trying to login, change your password, create an
npm ERR! authentication token or enable two-factor authentication then
npm ERR! that means you likely typed your password in incorrectly.
npm ERR! Please try again, or recover your password at:
npm ERR!     https://www.npmjs.com/forgot
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you were doing some other operation then your saved credentials are
npm ERR! probably out of date. To correct this please try logging in again with:
npm ERR!     npm login
```

Even after log in on site [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/)- still getting error
Tried to remove package-lock.json ,  .npmrc and node_modules folder - still getting error.
What can cause to such errors ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for quick reply . As mentioned there npm-cli-login  is incompatible with >=node18 I also tried to add token into .npmjs file - but it did not work also